serve django staticfiles with nginx inside docker
I have problem with staticfiles for django admin panel. for rest framework frontend panel the files are served without problem
settings.py
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
STATIC_ROOT.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

docker-compose:
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
#      - static_volume:/usr/share/nginx/html/static

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
#      - static_volume:/usr/share/nginx/html/static  # Ensure this matches the alias in nginx.conf
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles

volumes:
  static_volume:

nginx/conf.d.default.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static;  # Ensure this matches the volume mapping in docker-compose.yml
        autoindex on;  # Optionally enable to troubleshoot file listing
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

It's my first time building app using django, gunicorn, nginx
my config files are from chatgpt and tutorials. if i'm doing some mistake and someone will point it it'd great

You mixed up static_volume mapping. For nginx container it should be mapped to location path /usr/share/nginx/html/static, for django container it should be mapped to BASE_DIR / "staticfiles". Also for alias in nginx config trailing slash must match with location.

Does this answer your question? nginx does not seeing static files, when launching with docker compose +gunicorn

I tried following, collect static gathered files in settings.STATIC_ROOT successfully, I changed configs, then those static files got copied into nginx container to /usr/share/nginx/html/static. I checked both folders if they contain files. They contain. but overall result was unsuccessful. the files aren't served.

Show updated config.
